# promise me return a pending state when I use a callback

Tags: javascript, methods, promise, callback, fetch-api

I  test the fetch API with a callback, but my function returns "Promise State: Pending", and I don't understand why :

```
async function getJson(url, callback) {
  await fetch(url)
    .then(async function(response) {
      return await response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      callback(data)
    })
}

let getData = {
  getAll: async function() {
    await getJson('js/getJson/data.json', function(data) {
      console.log(data.photographers) //OK
      let test = data.photographers
      return test

    })
  }
}

console.log(getData.getAll()); //return promise pending
```

Thanks

Comment: Your `getAll()` method is async, so it will wrap the returned value (in this case `undefined`), in a Promise. You're combining async/await and callbacks, you shouldn't mix them, instead, use one or the other.

Comment: Why do people assume they can just put `await` wherever they want to and it will do something useful?  Please read what `await` actually does before trying to use it.  It ONLY does something useful when awaiting a promise!  And, returning a value from an asycnhronous callback also rarely does anything useful as it just goes back to the asynchronous caller, not as a return value from your higher level function.  There's lots to learn here about asynchronous programming.

Comment: With different tests I get,

"undefined"
or
promises fullfiled: undefined

I really do not master, this is the first time that I test this.

Comment: And, `return await response.json()` does nothing useful compared to `return response.json()`.  Either way you're returning a promise that resolves with the resolved value of the `response.json()` promise.  Please don't just go sticking `await` wherever you feel like it thinking it might do something useful.  Learn what it's useful for before using it.

Comment: And, ALL async functions return a promise - always!  So, both your functions you define will always return a promise.  The resolved value of that promise will be the eventual return value inside the `async` function (not the return value in some embedded callback).  Since neither of your `async` functions has any return value, both will return promises that resolved to `undefined`.

Comment: We need a canonical duplicate for this type of question as some variant of this is asked at least 5 times a day.  You could probably find dozens of duplicates if you searched.  I get that asynchronous programming in Javascript is a new topic to most people, but it is worth spending some time actually reading and studying about it rather than just plowing ahead and throwing `await` around.  One really needs to learn how promises work and then how `async/await` work with promises to do their job.  And, as has already been said in other comments, do not mix asynchronous callbacks with promises.

Comment: Precisely I am in apprenticeship.
I am new to the fetch method.

And I searched but I did not find answers using a callback

Comment: A piece of advice.  Don't use a plain callback with a function like `fetch()` that already returns a promise.  Just return that promise from `getJson()` and the caller should use the promise.  Get rid of all plain callbacks.  Use promises for all asynchronous work.  If an API doesn't have a promise interface, then take the plain callback interface and wrap it in a promise so you can program only with promise logic.

Comment: But I understand your annoyance, I made the nag by putting await and async everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General advice for asynchronous and promise-based programming listed below...

Here's what `getJson()` should look like:

```
function getJson(url, callback) {
  return fetch(url).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
  });
}
```

Just return the promise that `fetch()` already returned - don't try to convert to a callback.  Converting a promise-based interface to a callback interface is going backwards in terms of programming usability.  Promises are much better to program with than plain callbacks for asynchronous programming.

Here's how `getAll()` can then use it:

```
const getData = {
  getAll: async function() {
    const data = await getJson('js/getJson/data.json');
    return data.photographers;
  }
}
```

Or, equally good (and equivalent to the above example) would be this:

```
const getData = {
  getAll: function() {
    return getJson('js/getJson/data.json').then(data => {
        return data.photographers;
    });
  }
}
```

`await` has significant advantages when you are sequencing more than one asynchronous operation, but usually doesn't really help much when there's just one asynchronous operation.  It's not wrong to use it then, it just doesn't really offer much help.

And, here's how one would call `getAll()`:

```
getData.getAll().then(photographers => {
    console.log(photographers);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**General Advice and Explanation:**

**1. Read and study how `async` and `await` work with promises.**  Only use it once you understand that and then you will only be using `await` when you are awaiting a promise.  `await` does nothing useful unless you are awaiting a promise so if you're awaiting a function call, then that function must be returning a promise and that promise must be connected to when the asynchronous operations in that function are completed.

**2. Don't mix plain callbacks and promises.**  If you are programming with a promise interface, use that promise - never convert it to a plain callback.  Return a promise from your function and let the caller use that.  Among the many, many reasons that promises were invented is that control flow in non-simple asynchronous operations is massively simpler with promises (particularly asynchronous error handling and error propagation to higher levels).

**3. Convert plain callbacks to promises.**  If you encounter an asynchronous operation that you want to use in a world where there are other promise-based asynchronous operations (such as `fetch()`), then wrap the plain callback into a promise interface so you are only mixing promise-based calls with other promise-based calls.  Much, much simpler to code reliably.

**4. `async` functions ALWAYS return a promise.**  That's how they are built internal to Javascript.  So, a caller of an `async` function always gets back a promise as the return value. That promise will initially be in the `pending` state.  It will be resolved sometime in the future and the eventual resolved value of the promise will be whatever value is returned from the outer scope of the `async` function.  If there's no `return` statement in the outer scope of the `async` function, then the resolved value will be `undefined` as it is with both your `async functions.

**5. A caller gets a resolved value from a promise with `.then()` or `await`.**  Those are the only two ways to get a resolved value out of a promise.  So, any caller of an `async` function that wants some value back from it needs to use `.then()` or `await` to get that value.

**6. If you have a promise-based operation inside a function and you wish to return it's resolved value from your function, then just return that promise from the function.**  That will allow the caller to use that promise to get the value.  See my `getJson()` implementation above for how simple that can be.

**7.  Avoid `return await fn()` and use `return fn()` instead.**  If you're using `return await fn()`, then you're already in an `async` function and thus the function is already returning a promise.  So, avoid the extra `await` as it doesn't do anything useful and just use `return fn()`.  If `fn()` returns a value that value will become the resolved value of the promise that your `async` function returned.  If `fn()` returns a promise, then the resolved value of that promise will become the resolved value of the promise that your `async` function returned.

**8. Returning a value from a `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of the parent promise.**  In the second `getData()` example above that uses `.then()` internally, the `return data.photographers;` statement sets the resolved value of the parent promise to `data.photographers`.  So, any caller of `getData()` will find that `data.photographers` becomes the resolved value of the promise that `getData()` returns.

**9. Returning a promise from a `.then()` handler chains the promises and the resolved value of the promise you return becomes the resolved value of the parent promise.**  Essentially, returning a promise from a `.then()` causes the parent promise to wait for the newly returned promise to resolve and it then gets its resolved value from that newly returned promise.  You can see this in play in the `getJson()` function where `response.json()` returns a new promise that resolves to the json-parsed body of the http request.  That resolved value will become the resolved value of the promise that the function returned.

**10. Don't pass a callback when expecting a promise back.**  If you're passing a callback to some asynchronous function, then most of the time that function will not be returning a promise because many asynchronous APIs these days accept either a callback or return a promise, but don't do both at the same time.  So, when looking to use `await`, make absolutely sure the function you're awaiting is returning a promise.  When in doubt, look at the doc.  If the doc is unclear look at the code for the function itself or run an experiment to see what the return value actually is.  As an example, most of the mongodb asynchronous APIs will return a promise if you do NOT pass a callback to them, but will not return a promise if you do pass the callback.  Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Indeed that I am confused by this novelty. Thanks for your advices. I will continue to do research tomorrow.

However, your code returns me:

getData is not function.

thank you very much

Comment: @raphaelparodi - I had a typo.  It should have been `getData.getAll().then(...).catch(...)` which I fixed a little bit ago.  Please keep checking back at this answer as I am going to continue to add some advice to it.

Comment: Wow !! Edited yesterday, Thanks again for all the details. You are a champion.

Answer (score 0):

It works, although it's not really what I wanted. Because I thought I could store my result outside of functions in a variable. But it seems that this is not possible in fact.

All this and due to the fact that I have to give an evaluation for my training. Fetch is not mandatory.

In the first version of my code, I didn't use it. I just did classes and function synchronously by loading my JSON into a variable and adding it to a script tag.

However, I wanted to do some tests because then I have to use the design pattern factory method. And I just tested and it works with your code. Thank you for taking the time to respond to me at such a late hour.

```
//we instantiate the factory
let factory = new identityFactory


     getData.getAll().then(photographers => {

        let identity = photographers
        console.log(identity);
        //we pass the identity in the factory
        let newIdentity = factory.createIdentity(identity,'all')
        console.log(newIdentity);
        showIdentity(newIdentity)

       
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```