# Await isn't waiting for promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, async-await

Good evening all!

I have been stuck on this issue for a while and I can't seem to solve it through sheer Googling and so I am reaching out to you all.

**Context:**
I am writing a small application that handles all the calendars and basic project information for all the interns at our company because my boss is constantly asking me what they're up to and I wanted to give him something that he could look at, so I decided to solve it with code whilst also learning a new framework in the process(Express).

Right now I have my routes all set up, I have my controllers all set up, and I have my DB cursor all set up. When I make the call to the route I have defined, it runs the getAllUsers() controller function and inside that controller function it makes a call to the database using the getAllUsers() function on the DB cursor, I want the code to wait for the DB cursor to return its result before continuing but it isn't and I can't work out why. The DB cursor code does work because it fetches the data and logs it out fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have put the three bits of code in question below, let me know if you need me to show more.

p.s ignore the 'here1', 'here2', etc calls, this is how I have been working out what's happening at any point in time.

**routes.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';
import controllers from './controller.js';

export default (app: express.Application) => {
    // Users
    app.route('/users').get(controllers.getAllUsers)
    app.route('/users').post(controllers.postNewUser)
    app.route('/users').delete(controllers.deleteUser)
    app.route('/user/:emailAddress').get(controllers.getUser)
    app.route('/user/:emailAddress').put(controllers.updateUser)
}
```

**controllers.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';
import dbcursor from '../services/dbcursor.js';

// Interfaces
import { Project, User } from '../services/interfaces.js'

const controllers = {

    // Users
    getAllUsers: async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        try {
            const dbRes = await dbcursor.getAllUsers();
            console.log('here 3', dbRes)
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Users fetched succesfully!',
                dbRes: dbRes
            });
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Failed to get users.',
                dbRes: err
            });
            
        }
    },
}
```

**dbcursor.ts**

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongodb from 'mongodb' 

dotenv.config();

// Interfaces
import { User, Project } from './interfaces'

// DB Client Creation
const { MongoClient } = mongodb;
const uri = process.env.DB_URI || ''
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const dbcursor = {
    
    // Users
    getAllUsers: async () => {
        let dbRes;
        try {
            await client.connect(async err => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("here 1", dbRes)
                const collection = client.db("InternManager").collection("Users");
                dbRes = await collection.find().toArray()
                console.log("here 2", dbRes)
                return dbRes;
            });
        } catch(err: any) {
            return err;
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like `client.connect` produces a promise, since it takes a callback. So, awaiting it doesn't do anything. Also, `return dbRes` returns *from the callback* it doesn't apply to `getAllUsers`

Comment: Every day, there are dozens of questions here where people throw an await in front of some operation and expect it to make magic happen. await ONLY does something useful if you're awaiting a promise that is connected to the completion of your asynchronous operation. And, nearly always if you're passing a callback to some function, then it won't be returning a promise. I'd suggest you read the 10 promise/await guidelines in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191127/promise-me-return-a-pending-state-when-i-use-a-callback/66191335#66191335) as several apply for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to mix callbacks and promises. Try not passing a callback to the `client.connect` method, and you should be able to `await` the promise as expected

```js
    getAllUsers: async () => {
        let dbRes;
        try {
            await client.connect();
            console.log("here 1", dbRes)
            const collection = client.db("InternManager").collection("Users");
            dbRes = await collection.find().toArray()
            console.log("here 2", dbRes)
            return dbRes;
        } catch(err: any) {
            throw err; // If you're just catching and throwing the error, then it would be okay to just ignore it 
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you @Shadab that has solved the issue, it seems so simple when you point it out. Is there a reason that it's not a good idea to mix them or is it just to prevent confusion like mine from occurring?